# Controlling a 24VAC solenoid with arduino

Tags: arduino, inductor, solenoid, tvs, solenoid-valve

I'm trying to come up with a design for controlling a 24VAC water valve with an arduino.

My current design :

[image]

I want to use a BT1308W TRIAC controlled by an arduino pin to activate the vale, I'm also using a smbj48ca TVS diode to suppress spike generated by the solenoid when it's de-energized. I was using a similar design using a relay and the arduino was reboting randomly when the solenoid was closed, after adding the TVS diode it's not happening but is the correct use for this diode?

Answer (score 1):

> after adding the TVS diode it's not happening but is the correct use
>   for this diode?

You need a back-to-back (or bidirectional) TVS diode i.e. one rated for AC. At the moment if you apply AC to the terminals (VAC1 and 2) and energize the triac it will short out the AC supply on positive half cycles.

Comment: You are right, the chosen smbj48ca is a bidirectional TVS diode, the symbol was wrong

Comment: Then you should be good to go.

Comment: Shouldn't pin 1 of the triac have a connection to the DC part of the circuit as well?

Comment: @Maple yes it should and the OP should make that clear in his circuit hence how could he have proven the original design worked albeit causing EMI issues. Good spot.

Comment: Why should the TRIAC have a connection to the DC part of the circuit? A triac is not just sold state relay?

Comment: @Marc a triac's gate needs current pushed through it to activate it - without a galvanic path from your VAC supply to GND, it won't activate. However, because it appears to work, there must be a connection in your circuit that you have omitted.

Comment: @Andyaka, well I tested the circuit with a mechanical relay and was having the EMI issues till I added the diode and then moved to using a triac so I really have not tested this design. won't be a problem mixing GND from the DC part of the circuit and AC ? should I use a optocoupler?

Comment: I can't say whether your 24 VAC system rails can be conected to GND. It's not unusual to find this type of connection of course but check with a meter first.

Comment: [What to do when a question is answered - take the tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)